# Inform App.vue a Service-Worker Event is Being Called

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, vue-cli-3

I have a project created using Vue CLI 3 with Vue's PWA plugin included. I would like to display a banner prompting the user to click an in-app “Refresh” link as described [here](https://redfin.engineering/how-to-fix-the-refresh-button-when-using-service-workers-a8e27af6df68) in the 'Approach #3' section.

But in my Vue.js app, because the service-worker code is executed in `main.js`, and my snackbar banner is built into my `App.vue` component, I'm not sure how to trigger my `showRefreshUI()` method once the service-worker `updated()` event has been called.

`main.js` (applicable portion)

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App';
import './registerServiceWorker';

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

`register-service-worker` (applicable portion)

```
import { register } from 'register-service-worker';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
    updated (registration) {
      console.log('New content is available; please refresh.');
      // I'd like to call App.vue's showRefreshUI() method from here.
    },
  });
}
```

`App.vue` (applicable portion)

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  mounted () {
    // Alternatively, I'd like to call this.showRefreshUI() from here
    // when the service worker's updated() method is called.
  },

  methods: {
    showRefreshUI () {
      // My code to show the refresh UI banner/snackbar goes here.
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

If I can't call the `showRefreshUI()` method from `main.js`, how might I pass something from the `updated()` event to `App.vue`'s `mounted()` lifecycle hook to accomplish the same basic thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The final working solution for me was to leave `main.js` untouched, and instead:

`register-service-worker` (applicable portion)

```
import { register } from 'register-service-worker';

const UpdatedEvent = new CustomEvent('swUpdated', { detail: null });

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
    updated (registration) {
      console.log('New content is available; please refresh.');
      UpdatedEvent.detail = registration;
      document.dispatchEvent(UpdatedEvent);
    },
  });
}
```

`App.vue` (applicable portion)

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data () {
    return {
      registration: null,
    };
  },
  mounted () {
    document.addEventListener('swUpdated', this.showRefreshUI);
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    document.removeEventListener('swUpdated', this.showRefreshUI);
  },
  methods: {
    showRefreshUI (e) {
      this.registration = e.detail;
      // My code to show the refresh UI banner/snackbar goes here.
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but I think you could use a [custom event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) for this purpose. Something like this might work for you ..

1) Create the custom event in your `main.js` ..

`main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App';
import './registerServiceWorker';

const updateEvent = new Event('SWUpdated');

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

2) Dispatch the custom event when the service worker is updated ..

`register-service-worker`

```
import { register } from 'register-service-worker';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
    updated (registration) {
      console.log('New content is available; please refresh.');
      document.dispatchEvent(updateEvent);
    },
  });
}
```

3) Attach an event listener to the document object in your `mounted` hook that listens for your custom event. Remove the event listener in the `beforeDestroy` hook ..

`App.vue`

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  mounted () {
    document.addEventListener('SWUpdated', this.showRefreshUI);
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    document.removeEventListener('SWUpdated', this.showRefreshUI);
  },
  methods: {
    showRefreshUI () {
      // My code to show the refresh UI banner/snackbar goes here.
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Well, after a bit of trial and error, this solution worked very nicely! Thank you. I couldn't get it to work when placing the Event Constructor in `main.js` for some reason. I kept getting updateEvent is not defined error. So I moved that code to `register-service-worker` and it worked just fine.  I discovered I also needed the returned `registration` object in the `updated` event over in `App.vue` so I availed myself of the `detail` property provided within the custom event syntax as well. So slick. Thanks again.

Comment: @Doug That's my mistake. I guess you could also just do `document.dispatchEvent(new Event('SWUpdated')` directly since you're only using it once. Anyway glad things worked out for you in the end :)